# CloneFunction then replace original function with cloned one in LLVM opt pass

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-c++-api

I am writing an LLVM optimization module pass and I want to be able to restore the original function if I do not like the results. So I wrote a ModulePass with the following basic structure:

```
while(cloneAndTryAgain){

    ValueToValueMapTy vmap;
    Function *F_clone = CloneFunction(F, vmap, true);

    .... trying out things on F

    if(cloneAndTryAgain){ //not happy with changes to F
        //replace F with clone
        replaceCurrentFunction(F, F_clone);
        F_clone = NULL;
    } 
}
```

**However, after running replaceCurrentFunction(..), I try to print F but I get a segfault. There is something wrong with F after trying to replace it with the clone.**

`replaceCurrentFunction(..)` looks like this:

```
void replaceCurrentFunction(Function *F, Function *F_clone) {

  Module *M = F->getParent();

  // New function will take the name of the current function.
  F_clone->takeName(F);

  // Insert new function right next to current function.
  M->getFunctionList().insert(F, F_clone);

  // Erase current function.
  F->eraseFromParent();

  // The new function is now the current function.
  F = F_clone;

}
```

Here's the segfault and stack trace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
(anonymous namespace)::SlotTracker::SlotTracker (this=0x7fffffff94b0, F=0x1b) at AsmWriter.cpp:438
438     mNext(0), fNext(0), mdnNext(0) {

#0  (anonymous namespace)::SlotTracker::SlotTracker (this=0x7fffffff94b0, F=0x1b) at AsmWriter.cpp:438
#1  0x00007ffff63c66dc in llvm::Value::print (this=0x6d4a30, ROS=..., AAW=0x0) at AsmWriter.cpp:2092
#2  0x00007ffff6fb536c in operator<< (V=..., OS=...) at /llvm/include/llvm/Value.h:318
#4 ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow you're using a bunch of unsafe APIs here, and some statements are not even making sense. For instance what do you expect from the last line of `void replaceCurrentFunction(Function *F, Function *F_clone)` which is  `F = F_clone;`? If you want "F" in the caller to be updated, you should end this function with `return F_clone` and call it this way `F = replaceCurrentFunction(F, F_clone);`.

For the actual LLVM API, the correct sequence is:

1. Replace all uses of the old function with the clone:
   `F->replaceAllUsesWith(F_clone)`
2. Save the name:  `std::string Name = F->getName()`
3. Delete F: `F->eraseFromParent()`
4. Rename the clone: `F_clone->setName(Name)`

Comment: I need the pointer F to stay live because I use it to create another clone, that's why I have F=F_clone

Comment: regarding `F=F_clone`, I was doing it incorrectly. I need to pass the pointer reference to the function to set it properly. So my new function prototype is now: `replaceCurrentFunction(Function *&F, Function *&F_clone)`. This means that F points to the correct thing in my outer loop, where I will clone it and try again.

Comment: With F being a pointer reference, then yes it makes sense. However this is not a great practice. You should return a pointer instead an do the assignment at call site.
The rest of the step I described are still valid (you should mark the answer accepted if it addresses correctly your question, otherwise let me know how to improve).

Comment: I think you need to add that last point to your answer -- that was the reason for my crash.

Comment: Well that wasn't (still isn't) part of the question, and isn't the main (or only) reason for the crash, but whatever, I added a mention of it.

Comment: No it is what I asked for! I wanted to get rid of the crash.